# How to set Crystal Report DataSource from XML file (JRC) Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports for Eclipse, and I want to open a report and set the DataSource from XML files and then print it.

As far as I know, the Schema and Data have to be set in a XML dataset for it to work, but I haven't managed to make it work yet.

```
ReportClientDocument report = new ReportClientDocument();
report.open("reportpath.rpt",0)

byte[] schemaXML = Files.ReadAllBytes(new File("schema.xsd").toPath());
ByteArray schemaByteArray = new ByteArray(schemaByteArray);

byte[] dataXML = Files.ReadAllBytes(new File("data.xml").toPath());
ByteArray xmlByteArray = new ByteArray(xmlByteArray);

DatabaseController dbc = report.getDatabaseController();
XMLDataSet dataset = new XMLDataSet();
dataset.setXMLSchema(schemaByteArray);
dataset.setXMLData(xmlByteArray);

dbc.setDataSource(dataset,"TableName", "TableName");
```

The report exports a blank PDF file. No error at runtime.
I'm thinking that maybe I got the XSD and XML files wrong, any sample is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question: The code is working fine. The problem lies with the XML and XSD files. I got them to work with one single element, and I am still trying to figure out how to make it work with a DataSet.

One correction in the last line of code:

```
dbc.setDataSource(dataset,"", "");
```

This way, it will automatically try to find the schema in the XML file